# Linq query - multiple joins and selecting 2 columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework to work with my DB and I need help forming a LINQ query that will help me to get columns LoginId and AccNumber. I need only 1 LoginId for every single AccNumber, doesn't matter which LoginId it is. As it stands now, there are about 800K LoginIds and only 5000 AccNumber. Therefore, at the end I need 1 AccNumber associated with 1 LoginId. So I should have 5000 rows and 2 columns.

---

Here are the tables that I need joined:

### Item

ItemId, AccNumber, other irrelevant columns

### Block_Item

ItemId, BlockId, other irrelevant columns

### Bookversion_Block

BookversionId, BlockId, other irrelevant columns

### Sudent

LoginId, BookversionId, other irrelevant columns

---

Ideally, I want to replicate this SQL query using LINQ (just trying to provide as much info as possible)

```
select
LoginId,
AccessionNumber
from Item I
outer apply (select top 1 * from Block_Item where I.ItemId = ItemId) BI
outer apply (select top 1 * from BookletVersion_Block where BlockId = BI.BlockId) BVB
outer apply (select top 1 LoginId from Student where BookletVersionId = BVB.BookletVersionId) ST
```

---

Here is what I tried, however, the results that I get back are not correct and I get back like 183,000 records and it takes like 10 minutes to execute this. This line "var uniques = q.ToList();" is the one taking a long time.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.Database.CommandTimeout = 1200;
    var listOfAccessionNumbers = GetListOfAllAccessionNumbers(context);

    var q = (from items in context.Items
             join blockItem in context.Block_Item
             on items.ItemId equals blockItem.ItemId into bi

             join bookletVersion in context.BookletVersion_Block
             on bi.Select(x => x.BlockId).FirstOrDefault() equals bookletVersion.BlockId into BVB

             join student in context.Students
             on BVB.Select(x => x.BookletVersionId).FirstOrDefault() equals student.BookletVersionId into st

             //'VH098334'
             select new { LoginId = st.Select(x => x.LoginId).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
             AccNum = items.AccessionNumber.ToString() });

     **var uniques = q.ToList();**

     IList<string> listOfLogins = new List<string>();
     foreach (var accessionNumber in listOfAccessionNumbers)
     {
         var i = q.ToList().Find(x => x.AccNum.Contains(accessionNumber));
         listOfLogins.Add(i.LoginId);
     }
}
```

Comment: `.ToList()` is taking a long-time, since that line actually fires the query against your database and will prevent lazy-loading. If performance is an issue and you would like to speed things up a bit, you could try to write a StoredProcedure and call that directly. Will be much faster than using EF. If you only need to select data and aren't going to insert, delete or update it, you could set `AsNoTrack()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate your linq operations, to hopefully see which one is taking the longest and where its going wrong.

Also, I suggest using a **dictionary** with accNumber as key and LoginID as value so you can make sure each accNumber is associated with 1 and only 1 LoginID.

```
Dictionary<string, string> uniques = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var q = (from items in context.Items
         join bi in context.Block_Item
         on items.ItemId equals bi.ItemId
         select items).ToList();

//var first = bi.Select(x => x.BlockId).FirstOrDefault();
var val = (from b in context.BookletVersion_Block.Select(bv => bv.BlockId)
           join a in q on b equals q.FirstOrDefault().BlockId into BVB
           join c in context.Students on BVB.FirstOrDefault().BookletVersionId equals c.BookletVersionId into st
           select new { LoginId = st.Select(x => x.LoginId).FirstOrDefault().ToString(), AccNum = a.AccessionNumber.ToString() });

//if (!uniques.ContainsKey(bi.AccNum))
    //uniques.Add(val.AccNum, val.LoginId);

uniques = val.ToDictionary(c => c.AccNum, c => c.LoginId);
```

Haven't tested it, so let me know the time taken and whether you get correct values.

The dictionary should ensure you get 5000 values, but I am not sure why it is taking so long, but lets fix the number of records problem first.

Comment: Try now, I didn't realize the joins were all missing something

Comment: I don't understand what you did? It seems like you just copied my query and didn't make any modifications...

Comment: Restructured my answer, entirely untested, so let me know how it turns out.

Comment: invalid syntax, and i changed the dictionary to strings

Comment: I realize I might be making it worse, but tried to fix the syntax, I just want to help you pinpoint the place its taking super long or where its going wrong so we can fix that specific part.